@solana/web3.js Cannot find module 'rpc-websockets/dist/lib/client'
In my node.js project I have "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk": "^1.3.1-beta.52" dependency, and it has this deps:
`-- @project-serum/serum@0.13.65
  `-- @solana/web3.js@1.91.8
    `-- rpc-websockets@7.11.1

When I try to do import { Connection } from '@solana/web3.js' and run the thing I get this error:
[INFO] 20:49:10 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.2, typescript ver. 5.4.5)
Error: Cannot find module 'rpc-websockets/dist/lib/client'

I dont understand whats the problem, probably something with module resolution, but I am not sure. I also checked and rpc-websockets are in the node_modules.
Any idea how to fix this?

Solved by explicitly stating "rpc-websockets": "7.11.0" in dependencies. It seems like latest version 7.11.0 is not compatible.

Issue is related to last release of rpc-websockets
I fixed this with adding
"resolutions": {
   "rpc-websockets": "7.11.0"
}

to package.json

I had the same issue today and I fixed it by importing the rpc-websockets/dist/lib/client by itself before importing the solana/web3.js:
import 'rpc-websockets/dist/lib/client';

import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  clusterApiUrl,
} from '@solana/web3.js';

This fixed the issue for me, because the rpc-websockets module was always there but the error was still showing even after downgrading the rpc-websockets or trying older versions of solana.web3.js.

Downgrading to rpc-websockets@7.9.0 using yarn add solved this for me

Just +1 as I'm having the same problem. Quick way to reproduce is creating a new NPM project (npm init), set "type": "module" in package.json and run npm i @solana/web3.js.
Trying to run any file (index.js) that just imports web3.js results in that error
import {} from "@solana/web3.js";
console.log("Hello world");

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rpc-websockets/dist/lib/client'


Tried also to convert everything to cjs, but still getting the same error

I downgraded to  "rpc-websockets": "7.10.0" which works for me.
Make sure to explicitly state this in package.json

So, this is pretty much what uafrontender suggested to fix the version to 7.11. However, Zac says that 7.9 works too and Yasser says that 7.9 works too.

Ok so what I did is to check for websocket version that I have using:

npm list rpc-websockets

and I have: rpc-websockets@7.11.1
so what I did is to downgrade to 7.11.0 using

npm install rpc-websockets@^7.11.0


If you are seeing an error like Module not found: Can't resolve 'rpc-websockets/dist/lib/client.cjs' when trying to use the SDK, you can fix this by adding the following to your package.json file:
For npm:
"overrides": {
  "rpc-websockets": "7.10.0",
  "@solana/web3.js": "1.91.6"
},

For yarn:
"resolutions": {
  "rpc-websockets": "7.10.0",
  "@solana/web3.js": "1.91.6"
} 

Notes: Note that even if you are not using Solana, you still need to include the @solana/web3 line below. This will be fixed in the next major SDK release (V3).
Source:
https://docs.dynamic.xyz/troubleshooting/react/cannot-resolve-rpc-websockets
